# OpenRefine Merging column values into a single Row

Tags: openrefine

i have a column with multiple rows that i would like to combine and have them as comma seperated values in a list. How would this be done?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Efi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called "multi-valued cells" in OpenRefine.

OpenRefine offers to [split multi-valued cells](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#fill-down-and-blank-down) or what you are looking for is to [join multi-valued cells](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#join-multi-valued-cells).

In the corresponding dialogs you can provide a separator like a comma or a string sequence.

Comment: Thank you, but it is possible to use that with rows of the same column to combine? i have tried that it didnt seem to work

Comment: OpenRefine will join all the rows of a [record](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exploring#rows-vs-records). If you do not have records it will just do nothing. But you can create one record for the whole dataset by adding an empty column **at the beginning** and adding a arbitrary value in the first row of this empty column.